# Existence and uniqueness solution of a differential equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If I have the following equation:

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t}y(t,r)=\int_0^1 G(|r-r'|)y(t,r')dr'e^{\int_0^t\int_0^1G(|r-r'|)y(s,r')dr'ds}-y(t,r)$

$ y(0,r)=a(r)$

where $G:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^\infty$ with compact support.

Do you know how I can prove the existence and uniqueness of the solution $y(t,r)$ with $(t,r)\in[0,T]\times[0,1]$?

thank you

Comment: Notice that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{\int_0^t\int_0^1G(|r-r'|)y(s,r')\,{\rm d}r'\,{\rm d}s} = \int_0^1G(|r-r'|)y(t,r')dr'e^{\int_0^t\int_0^1G(|r-r'|)y(s,r')\,{\rm d}r'\,{\rm d}s}$. This should simplify the problem.